# Find a nearest point

Tags: php

I have MAIN POINT with coords x=0.568 y=0.132

And I have array of points like:

```
0.545, 0.1488
0.74878, 0.487
0.4845, 0.5485
```

And I need to find nearest point to MAIN POINT by PHP
How can I do it?

Point 0, 0 it's mean top-right corner

Point 1, 1 meat bottom-left corner

Comment: Please give out more information. For what do you need this? Why do you need this. Is this absolute (x: 0 to 1)?

Comment: you have to implement Dijkstra's algorithm(http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75641/dijkstras-algorithm-in-php)

Comment: Point 0, 0 it's mean top-right corner

Point 1, 1 meat bottom-left corner

Comment: Just calculate Euclidean distance (or even squared distance) between each point with MAIN and find the smallest.

Answer (score 0):

If your main point is at (x, y) and another point is at (x1, y1), then the square of the distance between the two points is (x - x1) * (x - x1) + (y - y1) * (y - y1) (an application of Pythagoras).

The nearest point is the one that minimizes this value.

Answer (score 0):

This code will echo the key of closest chords. Hope this will help :)

```
<?php

$main_coord=array('x'=>0.568,'y'=>0.132);

$main_coord_total=$main_coord['x']+$main_coord['y'];

$coords=array(
array('x'=>0.545,'y'=>0.1488),
array('x'=>0.74878,'y'=>0.487),
array('x'=>0.4845,'y'=>0.5485)
);

$dif_array=array();

foreach($coords as $key=>$coord){

$difference=($coord['x']+$coord['y'])-$main_coord_total;

if(strchr($difference,'-')){
    $difference=substr($difference,1);  
}

$dif_array[$key]=$difference;   
}

$min_value=min($dif_array);

echo 'The closest coords key is:'.array_search($min_value, $dif_array);
```

Comment: In case of this kind of coordinates (-11.6168610, 37.6021070) as $main_coord then should I use the same above implementation?